# Empirical Distribution White Noise Tests

Tags: filters, noise

All common tests for testing if a time series is white noise are based on common distribution assumptions from which inference is made that a process is white noise.

However, in the case for most time series the underlying distributions do not follow traditional distributions (gausian etc). For this reason I would like to know if any white noise tests exist which do not use preconcived distributions and observes main white noise assumptions (finite variance, serially uncorrelated ( independent / statinonary) and zero mean).

Using density spectrum as to see if the density plot produces a flat line through FFT is not possible as the series is non stationary.

Comment: The longer your FFT block, the more closely white noise resembles a flat line.  Averaging multiple shorter FFTs of white noise will also approach a flat line.  However, neither is sufficient as a test of true white noise since a chirp synchronized to the FFT block will also produce a flat line.

Comment: I could have sworn I read, and commented, on this question on stats.SE a few hours ago.

Comment: as it is an stats and also a signal procesing through in psting in bouth.